# Why does this partial derivative break down?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to compute the derivative of $u(f(y),y).$ So,
$$\frac{du}{dy} = \frac{du}{df}\frac{df}{dy} + \frac{du}{dy}\frac{dy}{dy} $$
$$\frac{du}{dy} = \frac{du}{df}\frac{df}{dy} + \frac{du}{dy}.$$

But this gives me an expression containing $\frac{du}{dy}$ on both sides!! But every partial derivative can't be identically $0$, so uh, what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common confusion when people encounter partial derivatives. 
The derivative on the right hand side of the equality is the partial derivative of $u$ with respect to $y$, the derivative on the left hand side is a total derivative, not a partial derivative. It should read
$$
\frac{du}{dy}(y)=\frac{du}{dy}(f(y),y)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial f}(f(y),y)\frac{d f}{dy}(y) + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(f(y),y)\frac{d y}{dy}(y)
$$
from which we see that we cannot subtract off the partial of $u$ on the right hand side from the total derivative on the left hand side since in general
$$
u_y := \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \ne \frac{d u}{dy}
$$

Comment: I have no idea where the $x$ came from, I definitely never talked about an $x$. But in either case, what is $u_y$ with respect to this problem then?

Comment: @RandomWordMashup $u(f(y),y)$ is $u(x,y)$ evaluated at $x=f(y)$. I also added some elaboration.

Comment: Okay, so the line over the $u$ usually indicates a vector, but here it looks like all one-dimensional variables. What does the line mean exactly? What does the notation mean when someone writes $u_y$ if it isn't the full derivative?

Comment: Its a tilde, just to indicate that it is a different function. $\tilde u$ is a function of one variable, $u$ is a function of 2. $u_y$ is the partial with respect to $y$, in general
$$
u_y := \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \ne \frac{d u}{dy}
$$
In fact, often times it doesn't make sense to talk about the total derivative of a function of multiple variables, unless, as is the case here, the other variables depend on $y$.

Comment: So now this is even more confusing than before. $\bar{u}$ should contain two variables, $f(y)$ and $y,$ so I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @RandomWordMashup $\tilde u$ is a function of one variable, $y$. To make this concrete, if $f(x)=x$, $u(x,y)=x+y$, then $\tilde u(f(y),y)=u(f(y),y)=f(y)+y = y+y=2y$. I will remove the part about $\tilde u$, its apparently confusing.

Comment: So after the edit, there is now this extra $(f(y),y)$ coefficient next to the full derivatives for some reason, I am not entirely sure what that is.

Comment: @RandomWordMashup $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ is a function of two variables, we are **evaluating** $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ at the point $(f(y),y)$. This is what a partial derivative means. It's useful to keep the evaluations explicit since otherwise many people just starting out in calculus make the same error that you have.

Comment: Would that be the sane as just using $\frac{\partial u(f(y),y)}{\partial y}$?

Comment: @RandomWordMashup Yes, but then it looks really messy so the convention is to pull the arguments down.

Comment: Okay, thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Would it help if you used the symbol for partial differentiation ($\partial$) properly:

$$\frac{du}{dy} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial f}\frac{df}{dy} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$

Now you see that, on the left side ($\frac{du}{dy}$), you have the derivative of the composite function with respect to $y$, and on the right side you have the *partial* derivative $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ of $u$ with respect to its second argument (also denoted, somewhat confusingly, by $y$), taken at the point $(f(y), y)$.

Actually, maybe it would also help if we wrote at which point the derivatives are calculated (which is commonly omitted):

$$\frac{du}{dy}(y) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial f}(f(y),y)\cdot\frac{df}{dy}(y) + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(f(y), y)$$